# Calculate LCM of N numbers modulo 1000000007

Tags: c++, algorithm, lcm

I was solving following problem on LCM : **Calculate LCM of N numbers modulo 1000000007**

My approach :

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;
const ull mod=1000000007;
ull A[10009];
/*Euclidean GCD*/
ull gcd(ull a,ull b)
{
    while( b != 0)
    {
        ull  t = b;
        b= a %t;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
ull lcm(ull a, ull b) 
{ 
    return (a/gcd(a,b))%mod*(b%mod); 
}
ull lcms(int  l ,ull * A)
{
    int     i;
    ull result;
    result = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) 
        result = lcm(result, A[i])%1000000007;
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)/*Number of test cases*/
    {
        int N;
        cin>>N;/*How many Numbers in Array*/
        for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            cin>>A[i];//Input Array
        }
        cout<<lcms(N,A)%1000000007<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting Wrong Answer when I submit my solution.
The constraints are:

```
1<=N<=1000
and 1<=A[i]<=10000
```

**[AT IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NbqNMq)**

I guess I am getting Wrong Answer because of Overflow. How can I improve my Code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1000000007` is too big for me to take as an example. Let me use `17` for example:

```
LCMS(10, 9, 8) % 17 =
LCM(10, LCM(9, 8)) % 17 =
LCM(10, 72) % 17 =
360 % 17 =
3
```

This is what your code doing:

```
LCMS(10, 9, 8) % 17 =
LCM(10, LCM(9, 8) % 17) % 17 =
LCM(10, 72 % 17) % 17 =
LCM(10, 4) % 17 =
40 % 17 =
6
```

Which is wrong.

**[ALSO AT IDEONE](http://ideone.com/uGGcFS)**

Comment: The ideone code shows the output as 6 which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Just factorize your numbers into arrays of prime numbers, calculate lcms over these arrays and then multiply them back into answer.

first primes are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, ..
so, for example, 45 = 3^2 * 5 turns into {0, 2, 1, 0, 0, ...}

and

```
vector<uul> lcm(vector<uul> a, vector<uul> b) {
  vector<uul> res(a.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    res[i] = max(a[i], b[i]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

your approach is wrong as mentioned by [johnchen902](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040040/johnchen902).

Here is my approach:

```
for i=1 to n
    a.take i_th number as x
    b.reduce(devide) remaining numbers(i+1_th to n_th) by their gcd with x
    c.multiply x to ans and take mod of ans
return ans
```

[SEE AT IDEONE](http://ideone.com/1B8eFi)

Comment: Well, your approach works, but I cannot understand it, do you have a mathematical proof or explanation to it?

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach would be to prime factorize the elements of the array and keep track of the highest power of every prime for each element. LCM will be the product of these primes raised to their highest power in the array.