# Least common multiple modulo some p

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have to find least common multiple (`lcm`) of numbers `a1 ... an`.

To solve this we can use a recursive solution:

`lcm(a, b) = (a * b) / gcd(a, b)` where `gcd(a, b)` denotes greates common divisor of `a` and `b`

`lcm(a1 ... an) = lcm(a1, lcm(a2 ... an))`

**The question is:**

What if we are interested in `lcm(a1 ... an) mod p` where `p` is some **prime** number. `lcm(a1 ... an)` is too large to be stored in `int`.

Answer (score 3):

There have been some previous questions on the topic:

- [LCM of n numbers modulo 1000000007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574299/lcm-of-n-numbers-modulo-1000000007)
- [Calculate LCM of N numbers modulo 1000000007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633449/calculate-lcm-of-n-numbers-modulo-1000000007)

You have two options:

---

Option 1: The general trend seems to be to that if your values are still too long for unsigned long long ints then you need to work with the prime decomposition of your numbers. Take each number a<sub>i</sub> and break it into it's prime factors (2<sup>r</sup>)(3<sup>s</sup>)(5<sup>t</sup>)... . All you have to do to get the LCM is to take the largest exponent for each prime factor.

For example, the LCM of 15 and 18 can be done like this:

15 = (2<sup>0</sup>)(3<sup>1</sup>)(5<sup>1</sup>)

18 = (2<sup>1</sup>)(3<sup>2</sup>)(5<sup>0</sup>)

The largest exponent for 2 is 1, the largest exponent for 3 is 2, and the largest exponent for 5 is 1. Therefore, LCM(15,18) = (2<sup>1</sup>)(3<sup>2</sup>)(5<sup>1</sup>) = 2(9)(5) = 90. But, we can perform the modulo in this multiplication step because `ab (mod n) = ((a (mod n)) (b (mod n))) mod n`. So just mod after each step of multiplication.

---

Option 2: This one involves finding the GCD of a subset of a<sub>i</sub>. Save this as g<sub>0</sub> and divide all a<sub>i</sub> that is a multiple of g<sub>0</sub> by g<sub>0</sub>. Find the GCD for another subset of the new a<sub>i</sub> and save it at g<sub>1</sub>. Again, divide all a<sub>i</sub> that is a multiple of g<sub>1</sub> by g<sub>1</sub>. Repeat this until the GCD for all subsets of a<sub>i</sub> is 1. Then you just multiply all a<sub>i</sub> and g<sub>i</sub> under you mod rules. For example:

LCM(15,18,10)

GCD(15,10) = 5 so g<sub>0</sub> = 5 and a = (3,18,2).

GCD(3,18) = 3 so g<sub>1</sub> = 3 and a = (1,6,2).

GCD(6,2) = 2 so g<sub>2</sub> = 2 and a = (1,3,1). At this point, any subset of a will have a GCD of 1 and we are done.

Putting it all back together LCM(15,18,10) = 5(3)(2)(1)(3)(1) = 90

Comment: I thought I could some other way than factorization.

Comment: I added a second option for how to do it. It involves being able to take the GCD of the set of numbers, though.